# Авторизация на phpbb3 при помощи Delphi программы.

Tags: delphi

Нужно произвести авторизацию на phpbb форуме, из программы написанной на Delphi. Но не могу никак понять, как это сделать. Гугл тоже помогать сильно не хочет. Прошу помощи у вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего,при входе логин и пароль в хеш преобразоваться,и насколько помню логин не может быть русский,а если даже так,то кодируем ник в хеш и проходим авторизацию.
var a:TStringList; b:string; begin a:=TstringList.Create; a.Add('email='+Edit1.Text); a.Add('pass'+Edit2.Text); b:=IdHTTP1.Post('http://site.ru/login.php?id='+ Edit1.Text' + &pass='+ Edit2.Text')',a); if Pos('Ищем на сайте любой признак входа.',b)<>0 then ShowMessage('Авторизация прошла успешно') else ShowMessage('Ошибка авторизации'); end;

Answer (score 0):

снифером смотришь что передается при авторизации. После авторизации не забудь хеш спарсить, действия все через хеш будут делаться